# Angular Node JWT token authentication and page redirection

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, jwt

I am learning JWT token  authentication from https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/
.
I tried to implemnt it . It worked fine.Here, after authentication the control returns to the same page. My question is how we could redirect to a new html page (restricted resource , ofcourse !) from the client controller?

I have tried some thing like

```
  $scope.submit = function () {
        $http.post("http://localhost:3000/authenticate?uname=" + $scope.username + "&pwd=" + $scope.password + "")
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $window.sessionStorage.token = data.token;// Save jwt in the sessionStorage
                    $scope.isAuthenticated = true;
                    var encodedProfile = data.token.split('.')[1];
                    var profile = JSON.parse(url_base64_decode(encodedProfile));
                    console.log('encoded profile is  ' + profile);   
                    window.location.href="api/admin.html";                
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    // Erase the token if the user fails to log in
                    delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
                    $scope.isAuthenticated = false;    
                    // Handle login errors here
                    $scope.error = 'Error: Invalid user or password';
                    $scope.welcome = '';
                });
    };
```

the page redirection always results admin.html with "UnauthorizedError" which is caught in the server.Any help?

Comment: could you please post your server side code too.might be some issue with your `get()` in server side.